# Rails4 application on Heroku, Bootstrap work

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, google-chrome, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku, safari

This is my first question on Stackoverflow.

I am developing a Rails Web Application based on RailsTutorial.org. I finally succeed deployed my application online at yurilliam.heroku.com. Yet, it seems I can only view my ideal version on Safari. It seems Bootstrap is lost on IE, Chrome, and Firefox.

What can do I to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you open the Mozilla Firefox console, the security tab throws the following error:

```
Blocked loading mixed active content "http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css"
```

and the [Learn more](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Security/MixedContent) link.

A solution would be to add bootstrap.min.css to your files in heroku, and not to use the CDN anymore. Another one would be to use the secure version of the CDN link, using **https**. That is https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css

If it helps, +1 and accept.

Comment: Wow. Thanks for your explicit explanation. It really helps!

Answer (score 2):

I can clearly see some `mixed content` warnings in developer console. If you fix them your app should start working as expected.

Replace

```
href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cookie"
href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css"
```

With

```
href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cookie"
href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css"
```

Ideally do not specify protocol in for your assets so that it can be picked up by the browser depending upon request. So you can also use something like

```
href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cookie"
href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css"
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. It really helps!

Comment: great! this is an obvious mistake everyone makes.